# ASP Looping through an array inside SQL Statement

Tags: sql, arrays, loops, asp-classic, insert

I have a form that will have a varying amount of 'Answer" fields.  So I have tried building my array as such:

```
        match = "found"
        form_counter = 1
        i=0
        DIM pollanswer()
        do while match = "found"
        pollanswer(i) = lr_request_collection_dict("poll_answer" & form_counter)
            if pollanswer(i) = "" then
            match ="notfound"
            end if
        form_counter=form_counter+1
        i=i+1
        loop
```

Later in my code, I am taking those values and wanting to insert them into my database but this is where I am stuck because I do need to insert the first value by itself the then loop through the rest.

```
thisQuery = "insert into survey_2_surveyquestionanswers (surveyquestionanswer_surveyquestionid, "&_
            "surveyquestionanswer_answer, surveyquestionanswer_answerlabel, surveyquestionanswer_order) "&_
            "select @@identity, "& SQLQuote(pollanswer(0)) &", "& SQLQuote(pollanswer(0)) &", 1 "&_
            icount = 1
            ecount = 2
            for each arrValue in pollanswer
            "union select @@identity, "& SQLQuote(pollanswer) &", "& SQLQuote(pollanswer) &", "& SQLInt(ecount)
            ecount=ecount+1
            next
            ";"
            set thisRS = dbAccessObj.DirectQuery("live", thisQuery)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: never use @@identity, you wil get the wrong value if anyone ever adds a trigger onto the table that inserts to a differnt table with an identity.

Comment: @HLGEM: that comment might actually be helpful if you also provide the alternative.

Comment: @@identity is defined before this query as I am following a standard query structure.  I appreciate the heads up though being a Php guy and having to work in Asp.  :)

Comment: scope_identity() is better and still better is usuing theoutput clause to get the identity value. Lookup howoto use these in Books online./

Comment: I can look into the issue with the use of @@identity.  However, I am most interested in help with my original question; looping through an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you are inserting the first entry twice with the "for each" method.

You could use the indexed form:

```
for a_index = 1 to Ubound(pollanswer)
    arrValue = pollanswer(a_index)
    ...
next
```

This just omits the first array element.